# How to save image using libcurl

Tags: c++, c, xcode, curl, libcurl

I wanted to use libcurl for a project which involves getting an image from a webpage.
The URL looks like this:

http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/cgi-bin/anonymous/image.jpg

Using command-line cURL I can retrieve the image using

```
$curl -o sampleimage.jpg http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/cgi-bin/anonymous/image.jpg
```

I want to know the equivalent of this code in libcurl because I'm getting nuts right now. I got this sample source on the net, and it compiles and stuff, but I can't see the image file anywhere.

This is the code:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <curl/curl.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 

using namespace std; 

int main(){ 
CURL *image; 
CURLcode imgresult; 
FILE *fp; 

image = curl_easy_init(); 
if( image ){ 
    // Open file 
    fp = fopen("google.jpg", "wb"); 
    if( fp == NULL ) cout << "File cannot be opened"; 

    curl_easy_setopt(image, CURLOPT_URL, "http://192.168.16.25/cgi-bin/viewer/video.jpg"); 
    curl_easy_setopt(image, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, NULL); 
    curl_easy_setopt(image, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, fp); 


    // Grab image 
    imgresult = curl_easy_perform(image); 
    if( imgresult ){ 
        cout << "Cannot grab the image!\n"; 
    } 
} 

// Clean up the resources 
curl_easy_cleanup(image); 
// Close the file 
fclose(fp); 
return 0; 
}
```

BTW I'm using a Mac and I'm compiling this code on XCode which has a libcurl library.

**EDIT:**Problem fixed. I just used a full path for the fopen(). Thanks Mat! Please answer the question so that I can choose yours as the correct answer. Thanks!

Comment: Use a full path in the `open` call so that you know where to look.

Comment: I'll try. But how do I do it with mac? I know how to do it in Windows' filesystem, but not in a Mac. Thanks.

Comment: How do I message the guy who commented?! I fixed the problem thanks to that guy. Hey Mat, please answer, so that I can choose your answer. Thanks!

Comment: I got your comments - a notification gets sent automatically to the poster and the previous commenter when you add a comment. If you want to target a specific person in the comment thread, prefix their name with an `@`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a full path in the open call so that you know where to look.

Also you should look at the `perror` function so you can print the reason why the open fails when it does - saves a few headaches.

Last thing: initialize `fp` to null, or only `fclose(fp)` if it was really open. As it stands, if `curl_easy_init` fails, you'll attempt to `fclose` a random pointer.