# How to load Remote Image in Tizen Wearables using Native

Tags: image, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk

Hi I'm new to Tizen Native Development and would like to know how to load remote images like loading it using URL. Anyone can help?

Comment: Hi! Do you want to load and show the image in a view or load only raw information from remote image ?

Comment: I just want to load and show the image in a view.

Comment: Welcome Tizen! Do you want to load image from **internet**?

Comment: @msalt yes. specifically by URL

Answer (score 0):

We can use `curl` ([libcurl](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/)) to load an image from remote address and later view the image as Evas object.

I had used sample curl application available for mobile once [ `New Tizen project > Sample > Mobile > Native > Network > Curl` ] to load image from url. Though, there is no sample application for wearable, but it will work. Remember to include "curl.h" header file. You will find a text field containing address to load image from and target name to save the image. The image will be saved in `/opt/usr/media/Downloads` directory.

There is another sample project(native) named `UI Components` for wearable which contains necessary UI needed for your task. Find "Image" viewing option and source for it and you will see how they have loaded images as an Evas object. Set the path of downloaded image here as image path to load from.

If we put together all of this,

- Create a basic UI application for Wearable.
- Use a single line entry to input image url (Single line entry example can be found under `UI Components` project) If you want.
- Use `curl` to download selected image. Loading an image is like loading a remote file. As mentioned in the docs, we have to go through following steps:

  - [Initialization of session](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_init.html). This creates a curl handle to work with.
  - [Setting options for the transfer](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html) i.e image url/callbacks. You have to [set options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6645550/how-to-save-image-using-libcurl) like WRITEFUNCTION and WRITEDATA to save a file.
  - [Perform a file transfer](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_perform.html). The example code holds basic structure of a curl transfer.
  - [Cleaning up the resource](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_cleanup.html).
- Load images as [Evas Object](https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/native/2.3.0/org.tizen.mobile.native.appprogramming/html/sample_descriptions/ui_image_sd.htm). You can use [this](https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.3.1/org.tizen.tutorials/html/native/ui/evas_tutorial_n.htm#manage) and sample projects for reference.

Curl project from the sample server has these steps in file download portion.

I hope this will help to accomplish your task.

Comment: I looked up the libcurl documentation link you gave. But I cant find something in there that load some image. Can you update the link?

Comment: The documentation holds api reference for basic file transfer using curl. I have added steps for a curl transfer in the answer now. Put your image url inside curl_easy_setopt().

Comment: Is there someway to load it remotely and not saving it locally?